# Texto maior que o botão

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver. Fiz um accordion, como na imagem abaixo utilizando o bootstra 4, a versão desktop dele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém a versão de celular o texto fica maior e acaba extrapolando o limite, tentei utilizar overflow-x, mas o resultado não foi bom. Existe alguma maneira de quando o texto for ultrapassar o limite do botão ele vai pra baixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/yNR8r

Comment: Se vc colocar o `i` dentro de um `p` não funciona?

Comment: @leAndrade não funcionou :(

Comment: Coloca uma classe neste `p` e no css coloca **white-space: normal**

Comment: Funcionou! Mas agora ele tá quebrando na versão desktop tbm, tem como tirar esse atributo? Eu to usando o media queries certinhos, mas como o white-space já está "normal", não sei "cancelar" ele

Comment: Vai ter que usar **media queries**, sabe como usar?

Comment: Ahhhh, deu certo :) Na verdade eu estava com um bug no Brackets que não tava atualizando a página, apliquei o white-space: normal apenas para a versão mobile no media querie e funcionou. Obrigado!!!!!!!

Comment: Beleza, jóia que funcionou.

Comment: Se quiser pode colocar a resposta ali que eu marco como soluçãoi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-acrd" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> 
        <p class="p"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Quais convênios aceitamos?</p>
    </button>
  </h5>
</div>

<style>
.p{
  white-space: normal;
}
</style>
```